# Is every positive multiple of 6 the sum of two primes?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Hello,

Goldbach's conjecture states that every even integer greater than $3$ is the sum of two primes. I'm interested in a weaker assertion: has it been proven that every positive integer $n$ such that $6\vert n$ is the sum of two primes?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did this question arise?

Comment: I strongly doubt it. If someone had a proof of the weaker assertion, I can't see any plausible reason that the method wouldn't extend to Goldbach's conjecture itself.

Comment: I think it would be a major breakthrough to prove that every number divisible by $100!$ is a sum of two primes. 

Comment: @Steven Landsburg: the question arose tonight, when I came to consider what I call "n-symmetric sequences", which are, for any positive integer $n$ non multiple of $3$, finite sequences $(u_k)_{0<k\leq N}$ the first term of which is an integer coprime with $n$ and less than $n$, such that $u_{k+1):=u_{k}+6 \ \ mod \ \ n$ and such that $u_{N+1-k}=n-u_{k}$. See http://www.les-mathematiques.net/phorum/read.php?5,810982 if you read French.

Comment: @Mahdi, you can find any number of claimed proofs of Goldbach, Riemann, P = NP, etc., etc., on the web and even on the arxiv. They aren't hoaxes, but that doesn't mean they are correct. People make mistakes. 

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. This would imply that every odd number at least $7$ is the sum of $3$ primes, since you can subtract $3$, $5$, or $7$ according to its residue mod 3. But that is not known. The strongest results known are that every sufficiently large odd number is the sum of $3$ primes, and that every odd number at least $11$ is the sum of $5$ primes.

Comment: Doesn't GRH imply that every odd number at least $7$ is the sum of $3$ primes?

Comment: An aside, from someone who doesn't know any number theory: are there any estimates of what "sufficiently large" means in the quoted theorem?  I mean, do we know _any_ explicit upper bound on the number of cases left to check?  Presumably, this number of cases, if known, is larger than the storage capacity of the universe ...

Comment: @Sylvain JULIEN: I think so, http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1469323 @Theo: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1932763 this was the best known a year ago, according to Terry Tao. Looks like a pretty large exponential.

Comment: Specifically, without GRH the second paper lowers the upper bound of $\exp(\exp(11503)$ to the dramatically lower $e^{3100}.$ With GRH the bound can be further lowered to $10^{20} \approx e^{46}$ which is low enough that further theory and much computer time can finish the job.

Comment: @Will Sawin: Less than one year ago, Harald Helfgott uploaded a paper on [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1205.5252) with significant technical improvements in estimating the minor arcs of $\sum e(\alpha p)$.  The abstract suggests there is only a modest gap between what is known computationally (by very recent work of David Platt) and what is needed to verify ternary Goldbach.  I do not know if this has been pursued further.

Comment: Patience, please...